# How to get folder path of SaveDialog when that dialog appers for first time, before the file is saved?

Tags: delphi, filepath, save-dialog

When SaveDialog pops up first time and when FileName is '', and initial directory is not set,
how to get directory path?

Comment: I don't understand why this matters. By the time the dialog returns and a file has been selected, the file name includes the path. What makes you ask the question?

Comment: @David Heffernan - I want to check if file exists because if there is one, for example 'somepic.jpg' then FileName in dialog will automaticaly be 'somepic(1).jpg'.

Comment: That doesn't happen automatically in any file dialog that I have ever used.

Comment: Any other program that does something like that will already know where it plans to save the file, so the program *sets* the initial directory in advance. Just do that in your own program, and *this* problem goes away. Don't let the dialog box choose the default save path.